# Como deixar o MegaMenu do PrimeFaces na Vertical

Tags: primefaces

estou com um probleminha com o MegaMenu do PrimeFaces, não estou conseguindo deixar na vertical. Estou fazendo um código para testar, que segue abaixo:

```
<p:megaMenu orientation="vertical" style="margin-top:20px">
  <p:submenu label="MENU" icon="ui-icon-check">
    <p:column>
        <p:submenu label="Menu.1">
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.1.1" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.1.2" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Opcao.2">
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.2.1" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.2.2" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.2.3" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:submenu label="Menu.2">
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.4.1" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.4.2" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="TV.5">
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.5.1" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.5.2" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Opcao.5.3" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:column>
  </p:submenu>
</p:megaMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que o atributo `orientation` só funciona corretamente nas versões mais novas do Primefaces.

Testei com a 5.3 (Community) e não funcionou.

Testei com a 5.3.6 (Elite) e está ok!

Comment: Era isso mesmo, estou usando o maven e estava usando <version>5.0</version>, alterei para a versão mais atual e deu certinho. Muito obrigado!